# Performing a custom SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select all those rows in table `A` where column `x`'s value is present in table `B`'s column `y`.

I am new to writing SQL queries have have tried using different combinations of SELECT statement, COUNT function and WHERE clause since are a really long time, but was unable to do so.

Is it possible to do this using plain SQL queries or is something complex like procedure needed?

Comment: What you are searching for is JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical method is `exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1
              from b
              where b.y = a.x
             );
```